# django admin framework show related fields?

Tags: django, admin

in models.py,there are 2 models

## __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_*AAA****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

```
class AAA(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255,primary_key=True)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.city
```

## __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_*BBB****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

```
class BBB(models.Model):

    city = models.ForeignKey(AAA)
    # other columns we don't care

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.city
```

## __*_*__*_*__*_*___*what I want to do****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

in the admin framework,when you "ADD" a record in table "BBB",
you must choose a exists "city" from  table "AAA",
when this action id done,I hope the adding page can display the corresponding "province" to   remind user which province the current city is belong to.(you can set a temporary field in the add page while not in the model BBB,I don't want the data redundancy)

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you provided us with more background about your models - it's not clear what you want to ultimately accomplish with them. What is the use case fot the "Reservation" model?

Comment: you have 2 tables:"A" and "B".A's column are "city" and "province".B's column is just "city"(foreign_key arrow to A's column "city").When you "ADD" table "B",you choose a exists "city" from table "A".I hope the corresponding "province" can be displayed in B's adding form.

Comment: Why not just define AAA's `__unicode__` method as something having both fields, for example `return '%s (%s)' % (self.city, self.province)`?

Comment: My original thought is use the API of "admin framework",and add a simple javascript code,the javascript's action listener can detect the city's change and dispaly the right province.As to me,I don't want the return a mixture of city and province.

Comment: Many thanks to Ludwik Trammer.In fact,the "return self.province" can solve my question.